# How to construct a website URL based on User inputs (TextBox/Dropdown list) in HTML/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am very new to HTML and JavaScript...

I need your help to construct a website URL based on TextBox inputs in HTML/JavaScript?

I am looking for a HTML/JavaScript code to allow user to 
1) Select an Option from Dropdown list
2) Enter a number

using which a URL should be generated

For example:
Drop down list has #Years to select and user select year 2014
and in text box user gives input a number as 1234

Below is the peace of code I have, but not able to get the desired result :(

```
<select name="SelectYear">
<option value="13" ID="13">2013</option>
<option value="12" ID="12">2012</option>
</select>

<select name="SelectMonth">
<option value="J" ID="J">June</option>
<option value="D" ID="D">December</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="EnterRollNum" ID="EnterRollNum">

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var iYear = $("select#SelectYear").val()
    var iMonth = $("select#SelectMonth").val()
    var iRollNum = $("select#EnterRollNum").val()

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = <a href="some-website.com/url?year=iMonth&iYear&number=N&iRollNum&get=details"> Link </a>
}
</script>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: use GET method to submit the details of the input fields.

Comment: hi gaurav, can you please show a sample peace of code? thank you

Comment: updated with the code I am trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="myForm" action="some.php" method="GET">
<select name="SelectYear">
<option value="13" ID="13">2013</option>
<option value="12" ID="12">2012</option>
</select>

<select name="SelectMonth">
<option value="J" ID="J">June</option>
<option value="D" ID="D">December</option>
</select>

    <input type="text" name="EnterRollNum" ID="EnterRollNum" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
$('#myForm').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('action')+'?'+$('#myForm').serialize();
    $('#demo').html('<a href="'+url+'"> Link </a>');
});
</script>
```

You can see the working fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/grvngr/fak1s583/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi @Gaurav, thanks for the quick reply... here I need to construct complete URL like 
webiste.com/some.php?SelectYear=13&SelectMonth=J&EnterRollNum=a
and should be a clickable Link on web page.... is it possible?

the code I have shared, it was able to print the text with out any hassle, but unable to print a link on web page.... not sure if it is possible

Comment: where do you want that link to be seen?

Comment: thank you so much for looking into my problem... Sorry gaurav, May be I have not explicitly explained. I am generating link to a different website. for example I have a website abc.com and the html/javascript will be executed on abc.com website, but the generated link should be like xyz.com/some.php?SelectYear=13&SelectMonth=J&EnterRollNum=a . I have tried editing <form id="myForm" action="some.php" method="GET"> as <form id="myForm" action="www.xyz.com/some.php" method="GET"> but that did not worded. not sure whats missing.

Comment: link still as "http://fiddle.jshell.net/fak1s583/14/show/abc.com/someurl.php?SelectYear=13&SelectMonth=J&EnterRollNum=123" . however the alert(url); shows the required link as "abc.com/someurl.php?SelectYear=13&SelectMonth=J&EnterRollNum=123" . the puzzle is how to make the Link to have the required url?

Comment: it is in fiddle so the link is that, when you use this code in your application it will work fine, the alert link is the link which will show when you use this code,